# Moving Laravel causing @IF statement error

Tags: php, laravel

Before moving my project everything was working great. after I have moved it from my pc to laptop, my @IF statements stopped from working.

For example, this is a piece of navbar.blade.php my navbar is changing upon the type of account, after moving the project the if command doesn't check for the authentication, all users are dealt with as a **guests**

```
@if(Auth::check())

              @if(Auth::user()->Account_type == 'Student')
            <li><a href="/myprojects">My projects</a></li>
              @ENDIF

              @if(Auth::user()->Account_type == 'Admin')
              <li><a href="/AdminDashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
               @ENDIF
@ENDIF
```

After moving the project I have tried

```
Composer Install
Composer Update
composer dumpautoload
```

Nothing worked for me

Comment: Try after clearing the cache

Comment: change   `@ENDIF` to `@endif`

Comment: use `Auth::user()->Account_type === 'Student'`

Comment: @Davit there is nothing wrong with the logic, it is working on my PC

Comment: @Shibon unfortunately didn't work

Comment: @ALIISMAEEL Did you changed `@ENDIF` to `@endif` ? Give a try please and let us know.

Comment: what does the database read? did you try and print the result to the page outside of the if like so `{{Auth::user()->Account_type}}` to see if it is indeed the same? could be some database magic

Comment: How did you move it? Did you just copy the files over (e.g. FTP) or did you use git and clone the application?

Comment: @RossWilson compressed it and copied to my laptop

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@if (Auth::check())
    @if(Auth::user()->Account_type == 'Student')
        <li><a href="/myprojects">My projects</a></li>
    @endif

    @if(Auth::user()->Account_type == 'Admin')
        <li><a href="/AdminDashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
    @endif
@endif
```

Comment: How did you get on with this? did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

**perform following commands**

```
composer install
                     or 
composer update

php artisan cache:clear 
php artisan view:clear 
php artisan config:clear 
composer dump-autoload
```

if you are using Linux ubuntu please use sudo before performing any command.